# Restrict Pyramid to require login by default

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

How can I use pyramid so, that it requires a User to be logged in, unless I explicitly say it does not for a certain view?

Currently I need to add some required permission to each and every `view_config` I'm creating. If I forget one, I'll have a possible security risk. I'd like it the other way around, adding some free access tag on login etc. If I forget one of those, I'll have an inaccessible page, which will be discovered much more likely than the missing protection.

Right now I'll need some permission argument and some check against that in my AuthPolicy

```
@view_config(route_name='my_route', renderer='my_templ.html', permission='view')
def view_foo(request):
    # ...
```

I'd want something like having to add `permission=None` or maybe a second decorator like `@public_access` or whatever.

I'm currently actually only interested in making all my views accessible for logged in users only (and not to ask for a more specific permission). But using permissions seemed like the right approach. Any suggestions achieving a "logged in only unless explicitly specified" situation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`config.set_default_permission`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.set_default_permission) to set a permission for views for which none is set explicitly.

Thus you could do

```
config.set_default_permission('private_view')
```

and restrict the `'private_view'` permission to authenticated users; and then explicitly allow the some views, like login, for unauthenticated users.

Do also note that:

> If a default permission is in effect, view configurations meant to
>   create a truly anonymously accessible view (even exception view views)
>   must use the value of the permission importable as
>   pyramid.security.NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED. When this string is used as
>   the permission for a view configuration, the default permission is
>   ignored, and the view is registered, making it available to all
>   callers regardless of their credentials.

Otherwise access to your 404, 403 views will be denied...

Comment: Google FTW, I hadn't used this before either ;)

Comment: I actually think I did use it before. Could not find it after an hour of trying - neither with google nor SO, somehow. Now I have a place to look, if I forget again.

Comment: The magic words were `pyramid default permission` and the first link.

Comment: But glad that I could help and get over the 200 rep for today :D